# How do I find and replace a character in filenames in Windows 10 using command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-rename, bulk, batch-rename

I want to replace all the underscore characters (`_`) with a space ( ) in a filename.

How can I do this quickly, when I have lots of `_` characters to replace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell's [`Rename-Item` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item):

```
Get-Item .\path\to\file_name_with_underscores.txt |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("_", " ")}
```

You can do this for multiple files at once if desired:

```
# all relevant files in the current folder
Get-ChildItem . -File -Filter *_* |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("_", " ")}

# all relevant files in the current folder and all subfolders
Get-ChildItem . -File -Recurse -Filter *_* |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("_", " ")}
```